# If any word has starting and ending character as ?, then both ? should be removed in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove the words few question marks in my paragraph in my PHP code.

For example:

```
$str = " Hi ?How? are you? Hope you are good. ";
```

And the output should be:

```
$str = " Hi How are you? Hope you are good. ";
```

So the words in paragraph which has starting and ending character "?" (Question mark), then both question marks should be removed. Please suggest. Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Use preg_replace function

Comment: @AlenOblak Yes, but I don't know regular expressions more? So anyone can write regular expression for me Pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = " Hi ?How? are you? Hope you are good. ";

$newstr = preg_replace('/\?([a-z0-9]{1,}?)\?/si','$1',$str);
echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\?(\\w+)\\?','$1',$str);
```

This would match any "word" surrounded by `?`. The `\w` matches "Any word character (letter, number, underscore)". The `+` means, "one or more". If you also want to match `??` and remove them, you can replace it by a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = " Hi ?How? are you? Hope you are good. ";
$pattern = "/\?(\w+)\?/";
$replacement = '${1}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = " Hi ?How? are you? Hope you are good. ";
echo preg_replace("/\?(\w+)\?/", "$1", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest regexp would be `\?([^\?\s]+)\?` where your word is in group one then. You'll possibly have to escape it like php needs it.